# First Chance Exception access to path is denied (UnauthorizedAccessException)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I am running an application in Debug mode but I noticed after a few seconds, a First Chance Exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' was being thrown very often and continuously.  While this didn't prevent my application from running, I still wanted to understand what was going on and resolve the issue to help with performance.

It turns out the exception is "Access to the path 'XXX.dll' is denied".  This baffles me as it must be coming from windows when the application is attempting to access the DLL, which it must have already done successfully.

Running the application multiple times will cause the error to occur on different DLLs so the exact position in the application where this occurs is not deterministic or repeatable.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?
Why is it occurring?

Comment: I don't know about resolving it - it may be completely benign - but you can have Visual Studio stop when it happens so that you can review the call stack by selecting 'thrown' for all exception types in in `Debug | Exceptions...`.

Comment: @galford13x: Does your application crash after this happens?

Comment: @500 - That is exactly what I did, was enable Break on Thrown so that I could analyze it.  It does appear to be benign from a functional sense.  But I'd like to understand what is causing it so that I could resolve the issue if/when performance problems occur.

Comment: @Dominic - It doesn't crash, it runs as I would expect functionally.  Although as far as performance issues go, I haven't done that analysis yet.  My application is timing sensitive so there could be some impact there.

Comment: What does the call stack look like when this happens?

Comment: @galford13x: Is this happening when you have the Exceptions window enabled? (CTRL+ALT+E). If you are, can you turn off "Thrown" for the Managed assemblies, as this checker can report internal errors which are handled normally.

Answer (score 2):

### Assembly Binding Logs

If you think it might be related to assembly binding, use [Scott Hanselman's instructions](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) to enable FusionLog and view the assembly binding logs.

It will probably help you find and solve your problem, if it **is** related to assembly binding.

> Alternatively, just set the Registry keys your self. (I just memorized them, as I set them all the time.) Set `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\ForceLog` registry value to `1` and `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\LogPath` registry value to `C:\FusionLogs` or some path that exists.

### Example

[image: FusionLog Enabling]

Comment: Yes! ...with the appropriate path (use the Visual Studio Command prompt).

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the issue.  I am sure the binding is working fine as the application executes correctly.  And if I hadn't looked at the output while the application was executing I would have never realized an exception was being thrown.  I'm just not sure why there would be access issues (which appears to have no effect logically) regarding the .DLL

Comment: Oh ok @galford13x. Sorry that didn't help, but I've had issues with assembly binding **many** times in the past, so hopefully it'll help someone. :) If the application is executing normally, try setting visual studio to break on *all* errors. Maybe that'll help you figure out what the problem is (if the errors are not benign).